# Popular form ja criado com PHP(Mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Preciso de popular um formulário com informações do banco Mysql no evento onChange de um input Select.

Eu sei criar um formulário do 0 preenchendo a propriedade values, mas preencher um form já criado não estou conseguindo.

```
input type="button" class="botao_form1" onclick="ativarform()" value="EDITAR">
                                <input type="submit" class="botao_form1" value="CADASTRAR">
                                <script>
                                    function ativarform(){
                                        document.getElementById("sobrenome_cliente").disabled = false;
                                        document.getElementById("idade_cliente").disabled = false;
                                        document.getElementById("telefone_cliente").disabled = false;
                                        document.getElementById("estado_cliente").disabled = false;
                                        document.getElementById("endereco_cliente").disabled = false;                                           
                                        document.getElementById("cidade_cliente").disabled = false; 
                                    }

                                    function actionform(){
                                        /* AQUI O FORM DEVE RECEBER AS INFORMAÇÕES DO BANCO */
                                        document.getElementById("sobrenome_cliente").disabled = true;
                                        document.getElementById("idade_cliente").disabled =  true;
                                        document.getElementById("telefone_cliente").disabled =  true;
                                        document.getElementById("estado_cliente").disabled =  true;
                                        document.getElementById("endereco_cliente").disabled =  true;                                       
                                        document.getElementById("cidade_cliente").disabled = true;      
                                    }
                                </script>
                                <?php 
                                        function popula(){
                                            $conexao = conectar();
                                            $nome = 'nome_ciente';
                                            $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nome='$nome'");
                                            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
                                        }
                                ?>
```

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem o escopo do seu problema. O que exatamente não está conseguindo? O que você já tentou? Teve alguma mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 1):

Patrick, acho que você não está entendendo como é o mecanismo de mudar um form sem recarregar a pagina (acredito que é isto que está tentando).

O funcionamento é mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O formulário "conversa" com o servidor sem recarregar com a pagina, então vc "precisa" chamar uma segunda pagina que faça a montagem das opções (ou até o select todo), então ficaria assim, sua pagina pagina estática com os dois formulários:

Um para escolher:

```
<form>
 <select id="marca">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select> 
</form>
```

Outro para ser populado pela escolha do primeiro:

```
<form>
 <select id="modelos">
 </select> 
</form>
```

E uma pagina php para receber e montar os options

```
<?php 
  function popula(){
           $conexao = conectar();
           $nome = 'nome_ciente';
           $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nome='$nome'");
           $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
         }
?>
```

E um script carregado:

```
$("select#marca").on("change", function () {
  $.getJSON( "/pesquisa.php", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      items.push("<option value="+key+">"+val+"</option>");
    });

    $( "select#modelo").html(items);
  });    
});
```